# Syntax of docker-compose version 3 and above

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This might be a completely lame question, but I was going through the different directive examples of docker-compose and a thought came to my mind.

**Is there a syntax or a code-book that specifies the spacing syntax of the spacing that is written in `docker-compose.yml`?** Different examples online show different spacing.

I know that `tab` is not allowed in `docker-compose.yml`, but for the spacing part, which of the below stands correct -

`docker-compose.yml` : Here the spacing is 2 spaces each, for the services, directives and their values *(given using `-`)*

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  myservice:
    image: mysql:5.5
    container_name: contDEV
    ports:
      - target: 18530
        published: 3306
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /app
        target: /var
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=unpush
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=push
    networks:
      - cloud-nw
networks:
  cloud-nw:
```

`docker-compose.yml` : Here the spacing is 2 spaces each, for the services and directives but their values *(given using `-`)* are written without space.

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  myservice:
    image: mysql:5.5
    container_name: contDEV
    ports:
    - 18530:3306
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: /app
      target: /var
    environment:
    - MYSQL_USER=unpush
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=push
    networks:
    - cloud-nw
networks:
  cloud-nw:
```

`docker-compose.yml` : Here the spacing is 4 spaces each, for the services and directives but their values *(given using `-`)* are written without space.

```
version: "3.2"

services:
    myservice:
        image: mysql:5.5
        container_name: contDEV
        ports:
        - 18530:3306
        volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: /app
          target: /var
        environment:
        - MYSQL_USER=unpush
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=push
        networks:
        - cloud-nw
networks:
    cloud-nw:
```

Comment: This is how yaml works, indentation level can 2 spaces , 3 spaces, or anything you like but it has to be consistent across the yaml file

Comment: since you follow the yams file specs, spaces or tabs doesn't matter http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395